# How to interpret the localisation output in PAMGuard using squared array configuration in the 'Bearing Calculator' module?

Tags: pamguard, localisation, array, whistle-moan-detector

I am struggling to interpret the output of the ‘Bearing Calculator’ module in PAMGuard using a squared array configuration. I think I understand the primary angle as being right or left (please, correct me if I am wrong), but I am not sure about the secondary angle for this configuration that goes until 90 degrees. Does anyone is familiar with this module and this configuration?

Here one example of a localised whistle and its bearing output:
[image: Localised whistle in PAMGuard using 'Whistle Detector' (WMD) and 'Bearing Calculator' modules.]

Here is a sequence of the same whistle produced around the boat and we can see the animal moving:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11):

The secondary angle is the slant (vertical angle).

A planar array (a square), can resolve one horizontal angle between 0 and 360 degrees and vertical angle between 0 and 90 degrees. The vertical angle points either above the plane of the array or below it - it is impossible to know which. If the array is non-planar i.e. you add a hydrophone which is not in the plane - then you can resolve the vertical angle so that it is between 0 and 180.

The display in PAMGuard shows a surface of possible angles, with red most likely and blue least likely. The dot represents the peak of the surface and thus the localised horizontal and vertical angles. Note that if you add the map module then these angles will be plotted on the map display. They are also added to binary files as an annotation.

Comment: Great thanks, Jamie! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming your "square array" is planar, then the vertical angle of the localisation is ambiguous (could be up or down)